# How to make sure that all the python **pool.apply_async()** calls are executed before the pool is closed?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How to make sure that all the **pool.apply_async()** calls are executed and their results are accumulated through **callback** before a premature call to `pool.close()` and `pool.join()`?

```
numofProcesses = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=numofProcesses)

jobs=[]

for arg1, arg2 in arg1_arg2_tuples:
    jobs.append(pool.apply_async(function1,
                     args=(arg1,
                           arg2,
                           arg3,),
                     callback=accumulate_apply_async_result))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: @tdelaney just edited the arguments to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait on the appended [`AsyncResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) objects before exiting the pool. That's

```
for job in jobs:
    job.wait()
```

before the `pool.close()`.

But you may be working too hard here. You could

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for result in pool.starmap(function1, 
            (arg_1, arg_2, arg_3) for arg_1, arg_2 in sim_chr_tuples)):
        accumulate_apply_async_result(result)
```

- the default for Pool is `cpu_count()` so no need to add it
- `with` does the close/join for you
- `starmap` waits for results for you

A full working example is

```
import multiprocessing

result_list = []

def accumulate_apply_async_result(result):
    result_list.append(result)

def function1(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return arg1, arg2, arg3

sim_chr_tuples = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]
arg_3 = "third arg"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.starmap(function1,
                ((arg_1, arg_2, arg_3) 
                for arg_1, arg_2 in sim_chr_tuples)):
            accumulate_apply_async_result(result)

    for r in result_list:
        print(r)
```

Comment: I tried "for job in jobs:  job.wait()" but the processes went into sleep.

Comment: Right, you need to wait for the work to complete before you close / join. The for should have been iterating per completed item. You could put a print in there to check status. Are these jobs expected to take a long time?

Comment: Some take long time, some take little time.

Comment: Using "with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool", why it does not recognize (arg_1, arg_2) in parentheses from the for loop "for arg_1, arg_2 in sim_chr_tuples)" ?

Comment: Okay, the posted code should work and we can use that for other issues as needed.

Comment: At first, I didn't use map because it requires all the data to be present in the memory which causes memory error. Instead of that, I wanted to send data for each tuple (simNum,chrLong) in sim_chr_tuples and process that data using pool.apply_async(). But this time,  pool was closed before all the results are accumulated through callback function of apply_async().

Comment: Let me try it, let you know the result asap.

Comment: Okay, a memory error would be a problem! If you don't need to keep all of the results in memory, can process them as they are completed and the order doesn't matter, replacing `starmap` with `imap_unordered` or `imap` could help. You would have to do the argument expansion in an ntermediate worker that does `def worker(args): return function1(*args)`

Comment: Memory is an important issue for me. Data can be quiet big. Therefore, I need to handle them for each (simNum,chrLong) tuple and accumulate each result coming from each member of tuple. Other than the memory problem, the other issue is to ensure that pool is closed after all results are accumulated.

Comment: What do you mean by " You would have to do the argument expansion in an ntermediate worker that does def worker(args): return function1(*args)"?

Answer (score 1):

In such situation, the better option could be `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

This is part of `concurrent.futures` module.

And the module has a function `concurrent.futures.as_completed`, which can help you in knowing the status.

Comment: Is there a sample code to understand the usage of concurrent.futures together with concurrent.futures.as_completed?

Comment: Please look into example 6 of link : https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/86022/concurrent.futures.as_completed           this example is specific to  ProcessPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried that calling `close` or `join` will somehow cancel the jobs in progress, and that's why you shouldn't call them "prematurely", you don't need to worry about that. `close` tells the workers to exit *after finishing all work that's been queued*, and `join` waits for them to exit. Together, they are the simplest way to wait for all of your work to complete, so waiting for the work to complete before calling them would be redundant.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you mean. Could you please explain it again? This first close, the join is recommended. Isn't it? By the way, this way of calling resulted in exiting from the pool without finishing the accumulations that are done in callbacks, in my case.

Comment: What you say and what @tdelaney are totally different. You say no need to wait. pool.close() and pool.join() already wait for tasks to finish. Correct?