# Does pool.imap_unordered requires all input in the memory?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Does python `pool.imap_unordered` requires all input in the memory?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. `Pool.imap` and `Pool.imap_unordered` are ["lazier"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) versions of `Pool.map`, and do not evaluate items from the given iterable until they are about to be actually processed.

Excerpt from the documentation of [Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) that notes its downside compared to `Pool.imap` and `Pool.imap_unordered`:

> Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables.
> Consider using `imap()` or `imap_unordered()` with explicit `chunksize`
> option for better efficiency.

Comment: But the iterable filled with the input has to ready in the memory, right?

Comment: No, "lazy" in Python means to not evaluate the value of an object until it's actually needed, so what the documentation says about `Pool.imap` being "lazier" means that the given iterable would be realized only on an as-needed basis.

Comment: Ok, it is good for memory usage.I'm making pool.imap_unordered  calls by using a generator. So thinking that each time an inputList will be filled and handled by imap_unordered. However, it works for a small number of elements but stops running for a large number of elements. From the elements I mean the final size of the generator. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "stops running". Please update your question with a minimal, reproducible example that demonstrates the said behavior.

Comment: The main problem is I was calling pool.apply_async() but all the callbacks were not executed. And the pool was closed prematurely.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65350843/how-to-make-sure-that-all-the-python-pool-apply-async-calls-are-executed-b

Comment: Then as a recommendation, I used imap_unordered but it didn't solve my problem.